# Can you build a road on the other side of another player's settlement?

Tags: catan

Player A: Wants to expand to resource-rich area of board. They build two roads and plan to build a settlement and continue their road to the resource-rich area.

Player B: Also wants same location as player A for their next settlement. They build two roads, ending at same hex intersection as player A.  Player B builds their settlement first.

Player A: Still wants resources further away, so places another road on the **other** side of player B's settlement.

Player A has a road going into the hex intersection, and argues that they can build a connecting road going out of the intersection, regardless of whether another player has a settlement there.

Is this really a legal move?  If not, where in the rules does it specify that this it is not allowed?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [official FAQ](https://www.catan.com/faq/4624-roads-may-roads-i-build-go-through-other-players-settlements-and-cities):

> Can the roads I build “go through” other players’ settlements
>   and cities?
>
> *Answer:* No. If you build a new road, it must always connect to one of
>   your own roads, settlements, or cities.

The [inverse situation](https://www.catan.com/faq/4608-longest-road-how-can-i-interrupt-opponents-longest-road) is also interesting:

> Longest Road - How can I interrupt the Longest Road of a game partner?
>
> *Answer:* By building a settlement on an intersection within the Longest
>   Road. Of course, you have to observe all building rules when doing
>   this.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Wonder why; seems like an odd design choice to allow settlements to interrupt a road while disallowing "building through", which will end up with the same result on the board eventually.

Comment: @VolcanoLotus: allowing "building through" would diminish the competition for space (and diminish the need to be efficient in action in the game). That ultimately _reduces_ the strategic choices in the game. On the other hand, allowing roads to be cut _increases_ such choices, both for the road builder (place a settlement now, or keep building a longer road?) and for the would-be-interrupter.

Comment: So, although the end picture might be the same in either case, the impact on gameplay is not. And, both follow from the straightforward application of a simple rule based on _when the pieces are played_, not the eventual result.

Comment: @VolcanoLotus - What? Why is it odd? It's completely consistent! Both rules are based on a settlement stopping a road on one side of it being connected to the road (or road space if not yet filled) on the other side of it.

Answer (score 12):

From the [Settlers of Catan rulebook](http://www.catan.com/gamerules.html), page 4, section 3a:

> A new road must always connect to 1 of your existing roads, settlements, or cities.

If your opponent builds a settlement at the end of your road, you are no longer connecting your road to your existing road, you are connecting it to an *opponent’s* settlement, which is not legal.

Comment: To be clear, connecting a road to an opponent's settlement is not illegal in itself.